# What is a recommended way to store database information?

Tags: java, data-structures, mysql, json, jdbc

I am using a Java to connect to MySQL database. I want to iterate through this data and store it into a data structure. This data structure will be

```
JSON.parse()
```

and converted from server side to client. Can anyone recommend an appropriate data structure?

The database contains 4 columns. One int, two doubles and another int column, in that order.

I appreciate any input. I just want to make sure I go in the most appropriate direction.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to represent the data in a database table as JSON? The best way probably depends on what the table represents. Does each row represent an object, and each column represent an attribute of the object? If not, we need more information about how information is represented within the table.

Comment: Each column is an attribute of an object. I have an ID as a primary key as an incremental. Then, there is latitude, longitude and kilowatts used per area. 10 items in the database. I want to use Java to retrieve the data and store it into a data structure. This data structure will then be used to parse with JSON. That way I can use this data with JavaScript. JavaScript will be used to plot out heat map points on Google maps

Comment: Are you asking how to store data in tables having columns in a SQL database, or for an in-memory Java data structure to represent a row from the database?

Comment: In memory Java data structure to represent a row from the database

Comment: You're asking what data structure to use to represent *one row* from the database? Just define a class with two int properties and two double properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class that contains fields with the appropriate types for the columns in your table and with the same names as they will be represented in your JSON document. The class should contain little or no logic. Such a class is usually called a Data Transfer Object.

You should have another object that loads the data from your database into your DTOs. This is called a Data Mapper (you can use a library for this, eg Hibernate, or do it yourself ... ironically, your code will be simpler to do it yourself).

Another object can convert your DTOs to JSON. Again, you can use a library for this (Jackson is a popular choice, and doesn't tend to introduce complexity like Hibernate does) or do it yourself (perhaps using a library, eg Apache Commons "lang", to escape strings, which is annoyingly tricky to get right).

Comment: Thanks for the information. This seems valid enough to allow me to move forward in solving my problem.